# Where clause in list of class inside another class using Lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have the class "Group" and inside this class I have a colletion of class "User"

```
public partial class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.User= new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CodGroup { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> User{ get; set; }
}
```

My class User

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }
    [Key]
    public int CodUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CodGroup { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Active{ get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group{ get; set; }
}
```

I Have the collection `IEnumerable<Group> Groups`

The problem is, my collection of users inside each Group contains users inactive too, How do I take only the users actives in each group using lambda expression???

```
Groups.Where( ??? )
```

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to achieve... are you trying to get the users, or the groups with active users, or the groups where *all* the users are active..?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the groups with active users I trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get groups where *any* users are active, you want:

```
var groups = Groups.Where(g => g.Users.Any(u => u.Active));
```

If you want groups where *all* the users are active, you want:

```
var groups = Groups.Where(g => g.Users.All(u => u.Active));
```

Basically as soon as you express clearly what you want, the LINQ looks pretty similar :)

Comment: I trying to get groups where users inside each group are active only but this expression 'var groups = Groups.Where(g => g.Users.Any(u => u.Active));' get inactive users too, how i remove inactive users? Very thanks for your help @Jon Skeet

Comment: @MarcosVinicius: It doesn't give *users* at all - it gives *groups*. The group itself does contain the inactive users - but when you iterate over the users within a group, you can always limit yourself to active ones at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all active users from the Groups in a flat list you could use

```
IEnumerable<User> activeUsers = Groups.SelectMany(group => group.Users)
                                      .Where(user => user.Active);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I trying to get the groups with active users.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Now that you specified, [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19795912/2145211) beat me to it...